# CSV format is not loading in spark-shell

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, apache-spark, spark-csv

Using spark 1.6 
I tried following code:

```scala
val diamonds = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/got_own/com_sep_fil.csv")
```

which caused the error

```
error: not found: value spark
```

Comment: You need to define a `SparkContext` (in Spark 2.0+, a `SparkSession` can be used), see e.g. here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 1.6 shell you get `sc` of type `SparkContext`, not `spark` of type `SparkSession`, if you want to get that functionlity you will need to instantiate a SqlContext

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val spark = new SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: Dude literally i am beginner in spark ,can you  tell some more about query ,i didn't get you

Comment: you are trying to use  a variable called `spark` in Spark shell 1.6 but this variable was introduced in Spark shell 2.0 so the command fails because `spark` does not exist. In Spark 1.6 shell you can create a val `spark` by executing the code that I added in my post.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlContext` is implict object SQL contect which can be used to load csv file and use `com.databricks.spark.csv` for mentionin csv file format

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("data.csv")
```

Comment: .ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)

Comment: updated the ans to read csv and not "com.databricks.spark.csv"

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize instance using SQLContext(spark version<2.0) or SparkSession(spark version>=2.0) to use methods provided by Spark.

To initialize spark instance for spark version < 2.0 use:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val spark = new SQLContext(sc)
```

To initialize spark instance for spark version >= 2.0 use:

```
val spark = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSessionExample").setMaster("local")
```

To read the csv using spark 1.6 and databricks spark-csv package:
`val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("data.csv")`

Comment: dude  spark told me for package , so problem  is that i don't know  what package i have to install in 1.6  ,i have tried this :                                                                                                   $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0                  this is showing the error :   error: ';' expected but '.' found. which is sossimple to under stand but don't  know why it is showing me this

Comment: You need to install the spark-csv package. Refer the link <https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-csv>. Make sure you are using the proper version of Scala. If your spark is compiled using scala 2.10 then use ```$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0``` and if scala 2.11 then use ```$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0```.

Comment: i am using scala 2.10.5 ,when i paste your  above  package then it was showing me the error like  : error: ';' expected but '.' found.
which is confusing me bro

Comment: @abdulsattar provide your ```spark-shell``` or ```spark-submit``` statement you are using

Comment: bro i didn't get you?